# Android app crashes after a variable is loaded from component

Tags: java, android

I have quite a simple application. However, after I clik on the button, app crashes. Tried to debug it and the problem seems to be in first 3 row of the `onClick` method. Once I tried to get there values manually, not via those edit boxes, everything went smoothly. Any ideas please?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText_pocetKM;
    EditText editText_spotreba;
    EditText editText_cenaPHM;
    TextView textView_spotrebaO;
    TextView textView_cenaO;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText_pocetKM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1_pocetKM);
        editText_spotreba = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Spotreba);
        editText_cenaPHM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1_cenaPHM);
        textView_spotrebaO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_spotrebaO);
        textView_cenaO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_cenaO);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Double pocetKm = Double.parseDouble(editText_pocetKM.getText().toString());
        Double spotreba = Double.parseDouble(editText_spotreba.getText().toString());
        Double cenaPHM = Double.parseDouble(editText_cenaPHM.getText().toString());

        Double spotrebaO = spotreba * pocetKm / 100;
        Double  cenaO = spotrebaO * cenaPHM;

        textView_cenaO.setText("Cena za spotřebované palivo bude "+ df.format(cenaO) + " Kč");
        textView_spotrebaO.setText("Celkem bude spotřebováno "+ df.format(spotrebaO) + " litrů paliva");
    }
}
```

Comment: since you manage to debug everthing you must have seen the error thrown. What seems to be the error? The lines where you are using parseDouble might throw NumberFormatException. Also one of those EditTexts might be null and that will also thrown an error while calling getText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the logcat of your crash report. If the logcat was provided we could be certain of your exact problem. But anyway, as you've got rid of your crash by removing the first three lines of your `onClick` function, I suppose you're setting invalid inputs in your `EditText`.

You're parsing the text entered in the `EditText` to double which will fail if the input is not a valid `double` string. For example, it'll parse `11.01` fine when it'll throw an exception while parsing `Hello`.

So to check if the application is crashing for a parsing error, you might consider surrounding them with a `try/catch` block like this.

```
try {
    Double pocetKm = Double.parseDouble(editText_pocetKM.getText().toString());
    Double spotreba = Double.parseDouble(editText_spotreba.getText().toString());
    Double cenaPHM = Double.parseDouble(editText_cenaPHM.getText().toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that helped. :)